# Infinispan custom interceptors not working with Hibernate L2 cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, infinispan, second-level-cache

In my project i have to intercept Hibernate L2 cache calls in-order to set lifespan for some selected cached objects. The problem is hibenate cache calls never comes through the interceptor.

My Interceptor ( test code)

```
public class HibernateCacheInterceptor extends BaseCustomInterceptor {
   private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HibernateCacheInterceptor.class);

@Override
public Object visitPutKeyValueCommand(InvocationContext ctx, PutKeyValueCommand command) throws Throwable {
    log.info(this.getClass().getName() + " intercept.");
      if (command.getValue() instanceof Car) {
          return null;
       } else {
          return invokeNextInterceptor(ctx, command);
      }
   }

 }
```

My Cache definition ( infinispan.xml)

```
 <namedCache name="mycache">
    <customInterceptors>
        <interceptor position="FIRST" class="test.HibernateCacheInterceptor">
        </interceptor>
    </customInterceptors>
</namedCache>
```

`org.infinispan.Cache.put(key,value)` calls comes to interceptor but hibernate cache calls does not comes. Does hibernate uses different API to skip interceptors ? How can i intercept hibernate cache calls ?

Comment: With infinispan-7.1.1 and hibernate-4.3.8 there were some problems with above interceptor. It works when it put to `LAST` position, not the `FIRST` position.

Answer (score 1):

No, Hibernate cannot skip interceptors - all of the logic of core Infinispan is triggered from interceptors.

My guess is that Hibernate does not use the cache (when you open JConsole, can you see entries there in Infinispan?), uses another cache (without the interceptor) or buffers the entries before inserting to the cache.

You can try to set trace logging on both hibernate and infinispan.

Comment: JConsole shows the entries and customer interceptor's constructor get called when deploying the project in tomcat. However any cache calls does not comes to custom interceptor. Debug shows customer interceptor not included in interceptor chain `org.infinispan.CacheImpl.InterceptorChain` field. I'm Infinispan using 5.3.0 version.

Comment: With trace logging on org.infinispan, the interceptor stack is printed to the log (search for >>). If it was created but due to some error not included in the interceptor stack, you have to study trace logs/debug it - I cannot give you any further advice at this point.

Comment: Anyway, if it's a bug, don't expect it to be fixed in 5.3.x, development is at 7.1.x/7.2 now.

Answer (score 1):

There are easier ways to achieve this. As indicated in the [Infinispan 2LC documentation](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_using_infinispan_as_jpa_hibernate_second_level_cache_provider) (see advanced configuration section), each entity can be assigned a specific cache where you can tweak the settings declaratively. The easiest thing is to check which is the Infinispan configuration that's used in your application, copy the default cache used for entities, give it a different name and tweak it. Then, you need to define something like:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.com.acme.Person.cfg"
          value="person-entity"/>
```

Where `person-entity` is the name of the cache for that particular entity.

NOTE: Remember that if you're running on Wildfly or EAP, the property name requires indicating the deployment archive and persistence unit name. This is explained in the advanced configuration section.

Comment: Is this working if `com.acme.Person` is sub class and related hbm is <subclass>. In my case I need to cache only one object in java inheritance tree but all this tree have only one table.

Comment: The subclass is still an entity so should work AFAIK